# Startup failure :Started WPA Supplicant

Tags: arch-linux, startup

Why does my system boot stop at "Started WPA Supplicant"?

When I try to startup up my ArchLinux it pauses at "Started WPA supplicant" I had other problems which I solved like SDDM failure. And now everything shows OK. However the startup doesn't continue.

I've tried updating the system but it always fails.

Comment: Now I updated wpa_supplicant and it says The /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf is file no longer managed by pacman and if it was modified, it has been renamed to wpa_supplicant.conf.pacsave. Move it to the original location of needed.

Comment: The startup screen also says failed to start Load/Save screen.

Comment: If _everything_ shows OK, including that the machine started WPA supplicant, then your diagnosis that WPA Supplicant is faulty is clearly wrong.  You need, as has already been said, to describe your system's actions more accurately than this.  "it fails" is woefully inadequate, not least because there are two possible antecedents for the pronoun.  People are not telepathic.

Comment: After running yaourt -Syua it shows error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files) ttf-dejavu: /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf exists in filesystem.

Comment: Now I removed ttf-dejavu and I will retry update.

Comment: If you're still behind on [this](https://www.archlinux.org/news/ttf-dejavu-237-will-require-forced-upgrade/) ttf-dejavu update, you're missing updates since last october, there's no way we can help you until you've updated to the latest package versions.